# What is wrong with my CSS code? Getting wrong output

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to solve this homework. It says:

[image]

> I need to write CSS code that does the following:
>
> • Aside: 500 pixels wide
>
> • Center 75% of the browser window
>
> • Footer bottom

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Welcome to Our Site</title>
  <!--  google font  -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!--  style css  -->

  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url('super_hero.png');
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .container {
      width: 75%;
      margin: auto;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: activeborder;
      position: relative
    }
    #body {
      padding: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      /* Height of the footer */
      min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
    }
    .heder {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: antiquewhite
    }
    .footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: beige;
    }
    .aside {
      width: 500px;
      float: right;
    }
    .section {
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      width: calc(100% - 500px);
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heder">
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <div class="section">
        <p>section</p>
      </div>
      <div class="aside">
        <p>aside section</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>this is footer</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

However, I'm getting a very bizzare output that doesn't look like the question. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you also post how the erronous output looks like?

Comment: You have used the fixed with for the aside so if the screen size is less then the 500px then it will create the problem.

Comment: You can run the code snippet, it doesn't look like the image.... Or is it correct? I'm very confused. Teacher said it should look exactly like the pic

Comment: @skeptirit check the height of the html tag, you will be surprised :)

Comment: Yes, the height of the `html` tag should be set to `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/06h0fcd1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="section">Section</div>
        <div class="aside">Aside</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #FACD8A;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper {
    width:75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCD;
}

.main {
    height: 90vh;
}

.section {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    height: 100%;
}

.aside {
    padding: 15px 25px;
    border-left: 2px solid #FACD8A;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
}

.header, .footer {
    padding: 15px 25px;
}

.header {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #FACD8A;
}

.footer {
     border-top: 2px solid #FACD8A;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/jz66L8k4/
take a look at `#table` it's most important part
Also try resizing to see that aside is always 500px wide.
Btw. I think your background image should be inside images folder!

Comment: unneeded use of table based layout.

Comment: Why is table layout bad always bad? I mean this can be done with floats easily but I prefer tables when you need equal height columns!